# WORD: lower all elements of an outline by one level

Tags: microsoft-word

I have an outline in word and I want to lower the entire outline by one level.  so for example right now I have:

```
 1. header
 text text text

   1.a subheader
   text text text

   1.b subheader
   text text text

 2. header
 text text text
```

And I want to make it

```
1. superheader

   1.a header
   text text text

     1.a.i subheader
     text text text

     1.a.ii subheader
     text text text

    1.b header
    text text text
```

can this be done without manually indenting every part of the outline?

Answer (score 2):

Indenting an outline selection will only demote if a parent item is present.

For the examples, `#` indicates the cursor position and `>>` `<<` indicates selection before hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Example 1: No parent, indent without demote

```
BEFORE
1.  #Superheader
2.  Header
    a.  item
3.  Header
    a.  item

AFTER
    1.  Superheader
    2.  Header
        a.  item
    3.  Header
        a.  item
```

Example 2: With parent, indent and demote

```
BEFORE
1.  Superheader
2.  >>Header
    a.  item
3.  Header
    a.  item<<

AFTER
1.  Superheader
    a.  Header
        i.  item
    b.  Header
        i.  item
```

**EDIT:** If this method does not work, then your outline structure may be broken (from "forced" editing).  Try enabling "Show all characters" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>) which may make these forced edits more apparent.

Comment: that just increases the indent but not the actual outline level.  so the headers would be indented, but would still be `1. header` and `2. header`

Comment: nope. same thing

Comment: ok. I can make it work by highlighting all of the headers at the same time (by holding [CTRL]), but I have to highlight them all.  this is a pain because the outline has over 100 headers and sub headers and sub-sub headers, etc.  is there no way to do it in one fell swoop?

Comment: Highlight the entire block, not just the headers themselves.

Comment: tried that.  it just indented the whole block and didnt change the levels

Comment: See edited answer.  I explained the highlighting better.

Comment: right that's what I tried and it didnt work.  I wonder if there might be something weird going on witht he outline.  it's a technical document, so theres a lot of tables and paragraphs between the levels.

Comment: Users often become frustrated by the indenting, numbering, spacing, etc and manually force the changes to "make it work".  This "breaks" the outlining.  Sometimes enabling "Show all characters" (Ctrl+*) can make these manual edits more apparent for fixing.